# Auth Adapter in Laminas Framework

Tags: zend-framework, laminas

Recently I've upgraded versions of Zend Framework (or Laminas) from version 2.x to 3.x and I've running into a issue with authenticating users. My code worked fine with Zend Framework 2 and after searching google and trying to solve the issue on my own, I've think I've narrowed it down but I just need a little help.

Anyways, here is my code

Module.php -

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => array(
            Controller\RegisterController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\RegisterController(
                    $container->get(RegisterModel::class)
                );
            },
            
            Controller\VerifyController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\VerifyController(
                    $container->get(VerifyModel::class)
                );
            },
            
            Controller\LoginController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\LoginController(
                    $container->get(LoginModel::class, LoginAuthServiceGateway::class, LoginAuthStorage::class)
                );
            },
        ),
    ];
}

public function getServiceConfig() 
{ 
    return [ 
        'factories' => 
             LoginAuthServiceGateway::class => function($sm) {
                $db_adapter = $sm->get(Adapter::class);
                $auth_adapter = new DbTableAuthAdapter($db_adapter, 'users', 'username', 'password');
                
                $auth_service = new AuthenticationService();
                $auth_service->setAdapter($auth_adapter);
                $auth_service->setStorage($sm->get(LoginAuthStorage::class));
                
                return $auth_service;
            }, 
    ];
}
```

I don't know if this is needed as well but here is my module.config.php file

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\LoginController::class => ReflectionBasedAbstractFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

When I try to run the login code, I'm faced with an error regarding the Auth Adapter, at line 76 in my controller file which is as follows

```
 $this->auth_service->getAdapter()
    ->setIdentity($login->username)
    ->setCredential($this->model->handleLogin()->verifyCredentials($login)['pass']);
```

I think the error the actual service LoginAuthServiceGateway, but I am not entirely sure.

Oh, if this helps too here is an screenshot of the exception message

[image]

Any help would be appreciated, and if more information is needed I'll try to give more

Thanks!

Here is the code inside of my controller:

```
use Application\Model\Storage\LoginAuthStorage;
use Laminas\Authentication\AuthenticationService;
use Laminas\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

use Laminas\View\Model\ViewModel;

use Application\Model\LoginModel;

use Application\Form\LoginForm;
use Application\Model\Filters\Login;

    class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
    {
          public $auth_service;
          public $storage;

          private $model;

          public function __construct(LoginModel $model, AuthenticationService $auth_service, LoginAuthStorage $storage)
          {
              $this->model = $model;
              $this->auth_service = $auth_service;
              $this->storage = $storage;
          }

          public function indexAction()
          {
             if ($this->auth_service->hasIdentity()) {
                 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/user');
             }
    
             $form = new LoginForm();
    
             return new ViewModel(array('form' => $form));
          }


public function authAction()
{
    $form = new LoginForm();
    
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $login = new Login();
        
        $form->setInputFilter($login->getInputFilter());
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $login->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            
            try {
                if (!$this->model->handleLogin()->verifyCredentials($login)) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('Invalid username and/or password');
                }
                
                if (!$this->model->handleLogin()->checkSession(array('username' => $login->username))) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage('A session is already active with that username.');
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/login', array('action' => 'failure'));
            }
            
           // var_dump($this->auth_service);
            
            $this->auth_service->getAdapter()
            ->setIdentity($login->username)
            ->setCredential($this->model->handleLogin()->verifyCredentials($login)['pass']);
            
            $result = $this->auth_service->authenticate();
            
            foreach ($result->getMessages() as $message) {
                $this->flashMessenger()->addMessage($message);
            }
            
            if ($result->isValid()) {
                if ($login->remember_me == 1) {
                    try {
                        $this->storage->rememberUser(1);
                        $this->auth_service->getStorage()->write($login->username);
                        
                        $this->model->handleLogin()->insertSession(array('username' => $login->username,
                            'password' => $this->model->handleLogin()->verifyCredentials($login)['pass'], 'session_id' => session_id()));
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/login', array('action' => 'failure'));
                    }
                } else if ($login->remember_me == 0) {
                    try {
                        $this->storage->rememberUser(0);
                        $this->auth_service->getStorage()->write($login->username);
                        
                        $this->model->handleLogin()->insertSession(array('username' => $login->username,
                            'password' => $this->model->handleLogin()->verifyCredentials($login)['pass'], 'session_id' => session_id()));
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/login', array('action' => 'failure'));
                    }
                }
                
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/user');
            } else {
                foreach ($result->getMessages() as $message) {
                    $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage($message);
                }
                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/login', array('action' => 'failure'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->flashMessenger()->addErrorMessage("Invalid form submitted, most likely due to invalid credentials or empty values.");
            
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('home/login', array('action' => 'failure'));
        }
    }
}


public function failureAction()
{
    $this->layout('layout/failure');
}
```

}

Comment: Can you paste contents of your controller? Also `DbTableAuthAdapter` is deprecated.

Comment: I'm using the class Laminas\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter just with an alias as DbTableAuthAdapter

Comment: use Laminas\Authentication\Adapter\DbTable\CredentialTreatmentAdapter as DbTableAuthAdapter;

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are declaring `Controller\LoginController` twice.

The first time, you declare it in your `Module.php`

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => array(
            Controller\LoginController::class => function ($container) {
                return new Controller\LoginController(
                    $container->get(
                        LoginModel::class,
                        LoginAuthServiceGateway::class, 
                        LoginAuthStorage::class
                    )
                );
            },
        ),
    ];
}
```

But you also declare it in `module.config.php`:

```
'controllers' => [
    'factories' => [
        Controller\LoginController::class => ReflectionBasedAbstractFactory::class,
    ],
]
```

However, I'm not sure this last configuration will work. `LoginController` constructor requires three parameters, and none of them is `LoginAuthServiceGateway`.

```
public function __construct(LoginModel $model, AuthenticationService $auth_service, LoginAuthStorage $storage)
{
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->auth_service = $auth_service;
    $this->storage = $storage;
}
```

Therefore, `ReflectionBasedAbstractFactory` will create a "simple" instance of `AuthenticationService`, without an adapter.. and this will explain why you get that error (`$this->auth_service->getAdapter()` returns a null value)

You have two options, keeping only one declaration of `LoginController` in your configs, with proper corrections.

**First option**: (the one I suggest)
Remove the declaration in `module.config.php` and modify `Module.php` as follows:

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => array(
            Controller\LoginController::class => function ($container) {
                $loginModel = $container->get(LoginModel::class);
                $authService = $container->get(LoginAuthServiceGateway::class);
                $authStorage = $container->get(LoginAuthStorage::class);

                return new Controller\LoginController($loginModel, $authService, $authStorage);
            },
        ),
    ];
}
```

**First option:** use only `ReflectionBasedAbstractFactory`.
Remove the declaration in `module.config.php` and modify `Module.php`:

```
public function getControllerConfig()
{
    return [
        'factories' => array(
            Controller\LoginController::class => ReflectionBasedAbstractFactory::class
        ),
    ];
}
```

AND fix `LoginController` constructor:

```
public function __construct(LoginModel $model, LoginAuthServiceGateway $auth_service, LoginAuthStorage $storage)
{
    $this->model = $model;
    $this->auth_service = $auth_service;
    $this->storage = $storage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the error is probably at this line :

```
$container->get(LoginModel::class, LoginAuthServiceGateway::class, LoginAuthStorage::class)
```

It should be

```
$container->get(LoginModel::class),
$container->get(LoginAuthServiceGateway::class),
$container->get(LoginAuthStorage::class)
```

instead.

Comment: Btw, if as mentionned above, if you declare your factory twice, it will be overriden by the second one.